# ajax: force utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, utf-8

I have a webpage in UTF-8, defined in head

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Then I have the external .js file, containing the following code:

```
function ajax_db(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
//some variables defined

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"db.php",
            data:"u="+uname+"&p="+pass+"&m=1",
            dataType:"text",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
            success: function(reply){
                $("#regstat").html("<p class='status'>"+reply+"</p>");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

As you see, request goes to db.php, and if **m** set to 1 and not all the fields are filled in, it ends here:

```
$mode = htmlspecialchars($_POST['m']);

//Mode: 1 - register, 0 - log in, 2 - log out

if ($mode == 1){

if (empty($_POST['u']) || empty($_POST['p']) || empty($_POST['email'])){
    $reply = "Словенъска";
    echo utf8_encode($reply);
    exit;
}
//more code
}
```

Problem is, it's returning some mojibake instead of text. I tried to force utf-8 encoding wherever I could, I put in db.php the following lines:

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

No effect at all. Furthermore, if I remove the utf8_encode() function, question-mark boxes are returned, which should indicate that no utf-8 is used.

Where could the problem be?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Словенъска is already in UTF8; utf8_encode() will presumably double encode it, which is definitely going to come out garbled.

Comment: Well, as I said, when I removed it, resulting string was of question-mark boxes.

Comment: Sure; that's why I'm not providing a full answer :)  Just pointing out that double encoding is guaranteed to give you problems.

Comment: Could you try it with this metatag - <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and without the utf8_encode()?

Comment: You might also want to check the encoding of the db.php file to make sure you're saving it as UTF-8.

Comment: @Gary no effect. Besides, I'm using html5 doctype, that (thanks god) does not require those bollocks with http-quiv and so on.

Comment: @cbuckley Crap, I'm so ashamed =) You are right, I was lost in Notepad++ interface and believed it was encoded it in UTF-8, while it was in ANSI. While the problem is goofy, you can still repost it as a full answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Nordvind Gladly! Sometimes the simplest solutions are exactly what escape us :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also make sure that the db.php file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.